# DEPRECATION WARNING: Model.scoped is deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, deprecation-warning

I have the following warning:

```
 DEPRECATION WARNING: Model.scoped is deprecated. Please use Model.all instead.
```

Here are lines with scoped

```
products = ((params.nil? || params[:search].blank?) ? products.scoped : products.filter_with_criterias(params[:search].split(" "), options))
products = ((params.nil? || params[:state].blank?) ? products.scoped : products.where(state: params[:state]))
```

After simple change products.scoped to products.all i am receiving

```
Failure/Error: products = ((params.nil? || params[:state].blank?) ? 
products.all : products.where(state: params[:state]))

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `all' for []:Array
```

Comment: show us how you retrieve `products` in the first place. it says there that `products` is an array, so why doing `products.all`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `products` is already an array, so you should be able to just use `products` without the `.all`:

```
products = ((params.nil? || params[:state].blank?) ? products : products.where(state: params[:state]))
```